# Why does the image() function not work properly?

Tags: r, image

I have big binary matrix (0,1) and I want to visualize it so that every entry of my matrix is one pixel in the plot.
I use the `image()` function, but it does not work as I expected.
I would expect that, because the last row entries are all zero, then I should see no white pixels in the last row of the image.

Here is my try on a simple example with its output:

```
a <- list(c(0,1,1,0),c(1,1,0,0))
b <- matrix(unlist(a),ncol=2)
> b
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    0
[4,]    0    0
```

[image]

Comment: Try to transpose the matrix with the `t()` function.

Comment: I did it, but also give wrong answer

Comment: 0 is a value. Thus it is displayed. Use `NA` instead of 0 if you don't want `image` to assign a color.
`b <- matrix(c(0,1,1,0,1,1,0,NA), nrow=4, ncol=2)`
`image(1:4, 1:2, b)`

Comment: I need to assign color for 0 and 1, but it's assign in wrong way

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong way"?

Comment: means that, every element of matrix  should be one pixel, but image function does not care about it.

Comment: There are 8 pixels. Non-square pixels, but pixels.

Comment: Try `image(x=1:4,y=1:2,z=b,asp=1)` and keep in mind that `image` does _a 90 degree counter-clockwise rotation of the conventional printed layout of a matrix_ (`?image`).

Answer (score 4):

As the `image` plots the counter-clockwise rotation of the input matrix, you have to transpose it and then flip it to be normally plotted:

```
tb <- t(b)
ftb <- tb[ , ncol(tb):1]
```

Now you can use custom colors if you don't like the default ones, e.g. 0 is grey and 1 is red. Also using the `asp` equal to one makes each pixel of the image rectangular (from @koekenbakker's comment ).

```
image(x=1:2, y=1:4, ftb, col = c("grey", "red"), asp = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I dnt know about the image() function, but you can do this with EBImage package like this.

```
a<-list(c(0,1,1,0),c(1,1,0,0))
b<-matrix(unlist(a),ncol=2)
library(EBImage)
x <- as.Image(b)
display(x,method='raster')
```

Comment: EBImage is not available for the R version 3.1

Comment: try googling for it, then downloading it via biocLite